# How to assign one page variable to another page variable in front matter?

Tags: yaml, hugo

I want to use values of post variables in other variables. Firstly, insert the date of `lastMod` in `description`. Secondly, use the `description` value for `summary`.

Is it possible and if so, how?

My front matter:

```
---
draft: false
title: How to reuse post variables
date: "2021-04-21"
cover:
    image: "images/3153420617.png"
    alt: "post cover image"
    relative: false
lastMod: "2023-04-25"
description: "UPD 2023-04-25. Searching for an answer."
summary: VALUE OF DESCRIPTION HERE
keywords: "question"
---
```

Comment: You should give us more context on what you are trying to achieve. Yes, what you want to do can be done, but when and how depends on your goal.

Comment: @Jeremie I am sorry if my question is not clear enough. The goal is to eliminate double typing of some info since it is equal to another front matter fields. For example, my summary field should hold the same text as description. I tried things like `summary: $description` without success.

Comment: My question is: what is the end goal of using the summary field to store the description? This is the context we need. Otherwise, if you want to avoid double typing, just use the fields for what they are designed for, and modify your template/layout to use {{ .Description }} instead of {{ .Summary }} when you need the value of the summary field in your template for example, instead of duplicating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I find most appropriate is to use [yaml anchors](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#yaml-anchors). An anchor is defined with `&anchor_name VALUE` and is inserted with `*anchor_name`.

Applied to my question, it looks like this:

```
---
draft: false
title: How to reuse post variables
date: "2021-04-21"
cover:
    image: "images/3153420617.png"
    alt: "post cover image"
    relative: false
lastMod: "2023-04-25"
description: &info "UPD 2023-04-25. Searching for an answer."
summary: *info
keywords: "question"
---
```

Then, I can also put this into my default template to stop double typing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automate that **at the MD file level**, unless you generate your MD files automatically.

We don't have the context of what is your end goal. Two options to consider though:

1. the easiest one is to store the data in the appropriate Hugo variables, and modify your layout/template to use the variables
2. a more complicate option is to define your own set of variables, and then replace them, again at the layout level.

**file.md:**

```
---
draft: false
title: How to reuse post variables
date: "2021-04-21"
cover:
    image: "images/3153420617.png"
    alt: "post cover image"
    relative: false
lastMod: "2023-04-25"
description: "UPD %%LastMod%%. Searching for an answer."
summary: "This is my summary: %%Description%%"
keywords: "question"
---
```

**layout.html**

```
{{ $description := strings.Replace .Description "%%LastMod%%" .LastMod }}
{{ $summary := strings.Replace .Summary %%Description%% $description }}
<div class="description">{{ $description }}</div>
<div class="summary">{{ $summary }}</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I came up with another shortcut.